# SELinux "training" ( permissive mode logs )

Tags: selinux

Alright I've been skimming various articles and videos. They all say the same basic thing: start with the default policy, run in permissive to see what needs to be fixed. Then modify your policies to fix potential problems. Then restart strict enforcing.

In these references they suggest I run `ausearch` to get a more simplified version of the audit.log. So I tried one such report:

```
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(03/27/2015 02:58:34.764:439) : proctitle=/bin/sh 
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(03/27/2015 02:58:34.764:439) : arch=x86_64 syscall=getxattr success=no exit=-61(No data available) a0=0x1fef030 a1=0x7fc0dbf2ef9f a2=0x7fff6aaa1da0 a3=0x84 items=0 ppid=1 pid=3861 auid=unset uid=root gid=root euid=root suid=root fsuid=root egid=root sgid=root fsgid=root tty=(none) ses=unset comm=systemd-logind exe=/lib/systemd/systemd-logind subj=system_u:system_r:system_dbusd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null) 
type=AVC msg=audit(03/27/2015 02:58:34.764:439) : avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=3861 comm=systemd-logind name=kvm dev="devtmpfs" ino=11755 scontext=system_u:system_r:system_dbusd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:kvm_device_t:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1
```

It's hard to figure out what the message is saying, especially when I am faced with hundreds of these.

I've seen some articles where it says pipe the results of `ausearch` to `audit2allow`. This seems to be the cli equivalent of pushing accept every time a confirmation box pops up. It also assumrs the message was caused by an error and not some hacker trying to break in.

So can anyone suggest a rational way of analyzing the "output" of SELinux permissive mode?

Answer (score 2):

Many times, you'll be presented with information and are expected to pick out the bits that are relevant to your purposes. For example, when you `strace` a program you're going to have a boatload of output and are just going to zero in on just the parts that seem related to why you're looking at `strace` output.

The audit logs follow a similar rationale. Let's look at yours:

> type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(03/27/2015 02:58:34.764:439) : proctitle=/bin/sh

Not too mind blowing. It gives you a timestamp and the value of the executable's `proctitle` which is usually the process name. Not quite sure why `logind` has that as a proctitle, though.

> type=AVC msg=audit(03/27/2015 02:58:34.764:439) : avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=3861 comm=systemd-logind name=kvm dev="devtmpfs" ino=11755 scontext=system_u:system_r:system_dbusd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:kvm_device_t:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1

This is the actual SELinux error message and the thing you should actually concern yourself with the most. The `type=AVC` is what gives it away. `AVC` stands for `access vector cache` [which is an SELinux component](https://www.nsa.gov/research/_files/selinux/papers/slinux/node30.shtml).

The important parts to note are what's in the `denied` stanza (in this case `getattr`) which tells you what the program was doing specifically in order to be denied. After that we look at the source context (aka `scontext`) which will give you a sense of what the *general category* of the offending component was running in. In this case the full context is `system_u:system_r:system_dbusd_t` which shortened to the only part that's substantively meaningful (99% of the time) just `system_dbusd_t`. Doing the same thing to the target context we get `kvm_device_t`. The `comm` and `pid` fields are important and obvious. The exception happened to `systemd-logind` which was running with a PID of 3861.

**So putting it together** we have `systemd-logind` was running as `system_dbusd_t` and trying to do some kind of `getattr` on a file with a context of `kvm_device_t`.

Knowing what that means you should do is up to the admin. For SELinux's part all it knows is that such a thing isn't allowed by its policy so it gives you the details so you can make your own call.

> type=SYSCALL msg=audit(03/27/2015 02:58:34.764:439) : arch=x86_64 syscall=getxattr success=no exit=-61(No data available) a0=0x1fef030 a1=0x7fc0dbf2ef9f a2=0x7fff6aaa1da0 a3=0x84 items=0 ppid=1 pid=3861 auid=unset uid=root gid=root euid=root suid=root fsuid=root egid=root sgid=root fsgid=root tty=(none) ses=unset comm=systemd-logind exe=/lib/systemd/systemd-logind subj=system_u:system_r:system_dbusd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)

This is a little out-of-sequence in terms of how you presented it but I put it after since that make it easier to understand how you're supposed to read it. The `type=AVC` is the important part but it usually logs the actual syscall that failed so that you can get more details.

For example, given the program name, we know what `systemd-logind` is but if it were more ambiguous the `exe=/lib/systemd/systemd-logind` might let you identify which program that caused the error. Things like `auid` (the `loginuid` of the process) or the `uid` might also be useful information to have if you weren't sure why the executable in question was getting kicked off.

Hope that helps. If you have any questions I'll update my answer.

---

**EDIT:** Another thing on your last point. Usually you can look at the policy `audit2allow` generates and kind of glean what change it's making. It doesn't actually apply the changes until you insert the policy module. So you may still generate it and just look it over in a text editor to see if it's the sort of thing you'd want to allow to happen. Might be faster than tracking down the details by reading `audit.log` directly.