# SELinux policy for Pi-Hole

Tags: fedora, raspberry-pi, selinux, pi-hole

I am running Fedora Server 28 for ARM on my Raspberry and during the installation of Pi-Hole I got a warning message about SELinux being set to 'Enforced' and that because of it I cannot use Pi-Hole's admin page.

That is indeed the case, http://pi.hole/ returns a blank page, and without disabling SELinux / setting it to permissive on /etc/sysconfig/selinux Pi-Hole does not work at all.

The question is, how do I create a policy that allows Pi-Hole to work as intended while having Enforced status on?

#### Edit #1

I found this [question:](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192919/selinux-training-permissive-mode-logs)

> start with the default policy, run in permissive to see what needs to
>   be fixed. Then modify your policies to fix potential problems. Then
>   restart strict enforcing.

`grep hole /var/log/audit/audit.log` outputs many comm="php-cgi" and comm="dnsmasq" denials.

Could this solve my problem?

```
$ grep hole /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypolicy
******************** IMPORTANT ***********************
To make this policy package active, execute:

# /usr/sbin/semodule -i mypolicy.pp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Pi-Hole's GitHub:

> Pi-hole being a advertising-aware DNS/Web server, makes use of the following technologies:
>
> dnsmasq - a lightweight DNS and DHCP server

Solved my problem with:

`SELINUX=permissive` in /etc/sysconfig/selinux

`reboot`

`# grep dnsmasq_t /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -m dnscache > dnscache.te`

`# grep dnsmasq_t /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M dnscache`

`semodule -i dnscache.pp`

Verified with:

`semodule -l | grep dns`

Afterwards:

`SELINUX=enforcing` in /etc/sysconfig/selinux

`reboot`

Comment: I'd be grateful for any feedback or criticism that I can learn from or use to help me improve my answer